# Access property in C# via indexer

Tags: c#, arrays, properties

C# allows you to override the array indexer of the `this` property, like so:

```
int this[int index] 
{
    get { return _hidden[index]; } 
    set { _hidden[index] = value; }
}
int[] _hidden;
```

However, I'd like to access a differently named property via an index, like so:

```
int Hidden[int index] 
{ 
    get { return _hidden[index]; } 
    set { _hidden[index] = value; }
}
int[] _hidden;
```

I know I could work around this by using it as a regular parameter, as such:

```
int Hidden(int index) 
{
    return _hidden[index];
}
void Hidden(int index, int value) 
{ 
    _hidden[index] = value;
}
int[] _hidden;
```

However, I lose the convenience of a named property that way, and I'm essentially returning to publicly named get/set methods. Additionally, as I am behind the scenes accessing members of an array, the array indexing notation makes more sense conceptually for my situation.

Is there any way to combine the convenience of the operator with the array indexer?

Comment: Only by returning some object that has an indexer, otherwise no

Comment: What would you suggest, then? Should I return an array directly, or create a class which looks like an array and return that?

Comment: Maybe I'am wrong, but should not you create indexer in Hidden class? Then you will be able to use: `your_object.Hidden[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property cannot behave like an indexable item, unless it returns one. You have two options:

- return an array, list or other item that you already have behind the scenes
- create an object that provides an indexer and returns the values

The first one is simple, but it will allow changing the array/list/whatever. The second one can have only a getter, so it can be made read only.

I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be many lines of code to make a generic template with indexer and getter to encapsulate the actual object storing the values if it is needed.